# Pattern synonyms lead to unexhaustive pattern matching

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, pattern-synonyms

I've managed to construct the following "minimal" example that shows my problem.

Provided the PatternSynonyms extension is enabled

```
data Vec = Vec Int Int

pattern Ve x y = Vec x y

f :: (Vec, Vec) -> Vec
f (v@(Ve a b), Ve c d)
    | a > b     = Vec c d
    | otherwise = v
```

I get a warning for the function f saying

```
  Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
  In an equation for `f': Patterns not matched: (_, _)
```

If I replaced every `Ve` with `Vec` it wouldn't complain.
How does my singular pattern synonym interfere here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not implemented yet, see [#8779](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8779). I'm not an expect here, but I know that exhaustiveness checks are hard to implement in a lot of cases, like GADT or guards. Probably it is problematic for pattern synonyms too.

Comment: I'm sure there's stuff I haven't considered, but it seems pretty weird that this doesn't work. I would have assumed that a simple macro expansion would be enough for synonyms of any kind. Don't see how that would interfere with exhaustiveness checks. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Luka It's not that it's impossible, but someone has to do the work. Pattern synonyms are a totally volunteer effort.  And you are free to contribute an improved pattern checker, of course. :)